# PIC32 - PWM and Sin-wave

Tags: c, microchip, trigonometry, pwm, pic32

I am trying to make a program that generates sin-waves that i will output through a passive summer and thus make the microcontroller play sounds when i press buttons.

I have got the PWM to work, and can play notes using constant values, but I would like to use Sin-waves instead of constants.

Heres the code that ive come up with so far:

```
#include <pic32mx.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern void _enable_interrupt();

//Change length of the Steps.
#define step 0.00000000000000000001


struct Note{
int number;
int freq;
double A;
double x;
int play;
}Note;

struct Note array[12];

void gen(int i){
 float pi = 3.141592;
 double x = array[i].x;
 double freq = array[i].freq;
 double A = sin(freq*x*step*2*pi);
 x++;
 array[i].A = A;
 array[i].x = x;
}

void initNotes(){



 struct Note C = {0, 200, 0.0, 0.0, 0};
 struct Note Ciss = {1, 200, 0.0, 0.0, 0};
 struct Note D = {2, 200, 0.0, 0.0, 0};
 struct Note Diss = {3, 4100, 0.0, 0.0, 0};
 struct Note E = {4, 3900, 0.0, 0.0, 0};
 struct Note F = {5, 3700, 0.0, 0.0, 0};
 struct Note Fiss = {6, 3500, 0.0, 0.0, 0};
 struct Note G = {7, 3300, 0.0, 0.0, 0};
 struct Note Giss = {8, 3100, 0.0, 0.0, 0};
 struct Note B = {9, 2900, 0.0, 0.0, 0};
 struct Note Biss = {10, 2700, 0.0, 0.0, 0};

 array[0] = C;
 array[1] = Ciss;
 array[2] = D;
 array[3] = Diss;
 array[4] = E;
 array[5] = F;
 array[6] = Fiss;
 array[7] = G;
 array[8] = Giss;
 array[9] = B;
 array[10] = Biss;


}
void initSynth() {
 for(;;) {
  int btns = getBtns();

  // Check buttons. If button is pressed, corresponding note's play-value will be set to 1 (true)
  if((PORTD & 0b000000100000) == 0b000000100000){
       array[0].play = 1; 

  }else{
        array[0].play = 0;
  }
  if((PORTD & 0b000001000000) == 0b000001000000){
            array[1].play = 1;
  }
  else{
      array[1].play = 0;
  }
  if((PORTD & 0b000010000000) == 0b000010000000){
            array[2].play = 1;
  }else {
      array[2].play = 0;
  }
  // Check note-array for notes with play-value 1 (true). These are added together.

  int c;
  int nr;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){
   if(array[i].play == 1){
    c = c + array[i].A;
    gen(i);
    nr++;
   }
        }

  // Set PWM to previously calculated value.
  if((c/nr) > 0){
        setPwm((c/nr), 50);
  } else setPwm(0,0);
 }
}

int getBtns(void) {
  return((PORTD >>5) &0x7); /* Port D bits 5 through 8 is used for the Buttons and is set to 1 (input) */
 }

 int getSwitches(void) {
  return((PORTD>>8) &0xF); /* Port D bits 8 through 12 is used for the Switches and is set to 1 (input) */
 }

 int getbtn(void) {
  return(PORTD &0x1);
 }


void initPwm(){
 T2CON = 0x070; // Clear timer2, prescale at 1:1
 TMR2 = 0x0; // Timer2 value starts at 0
 OC1CON = 0x0000; // Turn off and clear pwm
 OC1R = 0x0001;
 OC1RS = 0; // Dutycycle
 OC1CON = 0x0006; // Configure for PWM mode without Fault pin
 PR2 = 0; // Set dutycycle, HÄR ÄNDRAR MAN TONER!
 IECSET(0) = 0x0100; // Enable T2 interrupt
 IPCSET(2) = 0x01C; // Set T2 interrupt priority to 7
 enable_interrupt();
 OC1CONSET = 0x08000; // Enable OC1
 T2CONSET |= 0x08000; // Enable Timer2
}

void setPwm(int pwm, int duty){
    int dutycycle = 0xFFFFFFFF * (duty / 100);
 OC1RS = duty;
 PR2 = pwm;
}

int main(void) {
 TRISE = 0x00; /* Port E bits 0 through 7 is used for the LED and is set to 0 (output) */
 PORTE = 0x00;
 initNotes();
 initPwm();
 initSynth();
 return 0;
}

void user_isr( void ) {
 if((IFS(0)&0x0100)==0x0100){
  IFSCLR(0) = 0x0100;
 }
}
```

When i press the button the summer starts to buzz and tick at different speed each time i press the button. Sometimes I get clean tones, so I get the feeling that I am somewhat close to a solution. Is the problem that the computer runs at an alternating speed? Maybe the solution is adding another timer somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you are not running the PIC fast enough to get audible tones. You're PWM rates are probably in the low kHz or Hz range and thus sound terrible. Read about the OSC family reference manual and use the config bits to set up your PIC for 80MHz (if you're on a PIC32MX). http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61112H.pdf

Comment: AFAIK, not all PIC32MX's are capable of an 80MHz SYSCLK, for example, PIC32MX1XX/2XX/5XX are only capable of 50MHz (source: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001290E.pdf)

Comment: @bigwillydos The 7XX series are very much capable of 80MHz